# Android studio not showing updated app of flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I started learning flutter like a week ago and it was going very good so far but i made a mistake i.e 
instead of

```
style: new TextStyle()
```

i did

```
style: TextStyle()
```

it gave me an error which i immediately fixed but it still gives me the same error. I am so annoyed , i've tried every thing from uninstalling the app to even restarting the laptop and invalidating caches. I have no idea how to make it accept my updated code.

Answer (score 3):

Got it. Had to delete the build folder and then run the app again. Can't believe it was that big a mess.

Comment: I am also encountering the same problem, which build folder are you referring to?

Comment: there is only one folder named build i saw in the repository , it has your apk etc so when you delete it, it's rebuilds it from scratch